# is there any way to capture laravel error messages in a variable

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form in laravel 5 with all field being required. If the user doesn't input anything in the field, an error messages will be shown just under that field. The error message is shown like this:

```
 {!!$errors->first('Name','<div class="has-error"><span></span>:message</div>')!!}
```

...to give you an example, if the user doesn't input anything in the field "Name", the message will be: "The name field is required."

What I want is to capture this message in a variable, something like:

```
$mess=something;
```

..i need this something...

If i do `echo $mess` the result should be The name field is required.

Can you help me please ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want to capture the errors in the controller directly, right? Because you are using `$this->validate()` in your controller, thus returning you the errors and you can access is with the `$errors` variable. Is this correct so far?

If yes, then don't use `$this->validate()`, but this instead

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

if ($v->fails()) {
    return view('viewname', ['mess' => $v->errors()]);
}
```

This lets you save the `Validator` instance in a variable, and do the check manually. `$v->errors()` now contains all your errors, which you can return to your view as `mess`.

Comment: I don't use $this->validate() . I have controller that stores the data in the table with  public function store(CreateTableRequest $request), a Request class with the rules and a class that extends Eloquent. Anyway... if I take your code, where should I write it ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Texas You can write your validation directly in the controller class